# angularjs routing behaviour of content and function calls

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to [Angular.js](http://www.angularjs.org) which is why I have a basic question regarding routing. I figured out how to create routes and inject specific `.html`s by `$routeProvider`

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) { 
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
       templateUrl: 'routes/view2.html'    
    });
});
```

but what I really don't get is how content or function of `view2.html` are handled in Angular.

Lets take `view2.html`. It has a `<p>` with some text in a specific color. Nothing to special. But also it has a little slideshow which is called by `$('slideshow').cycle()` function.
All what happens is it displays me the `<p>` tag in a different color and no slideshow function is called on my rootsite of the app.

Could you give me some approach how to actually solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you put `$('slideshow').cycle()`?

Comment: actually it is in the `view2.html` where the related pictures are in. But I guess I'm having a logical problem about how angular is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just load required view and then compile it. During compilation Angular processes all directives in view.
If you want to do this proper(Angular) way you should put such code like `$('slideshow').cycle()` inside of directive. And then use it like

`<div my-slideshow=""></div>`

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .directive('mySlideshow', [function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element) {
        element.cycle();
      }
    }
}]);
```

[Directives documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

[Much more comprehensive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)